# Jenkins: Get build parameter from groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, plugins, jenkins-scriptler

I have a job with a text parameter called `LOCAL_IP` then I'm using Extensible choice parameter plugin to insert a Groovy Script, I'm trying to get the `LOCAL_IP` parameter with no success, anyone knows what I'm doing wrong? here is my code:

```
import hudson.model.*

def build = this.getProperty(‘binding’).getVariable(‘build’)
def listener = this.getProperty(‘binding’).getVariable(‘listener’)
def env = build.getEnvironment(listener)

return env.LOCAL_IP
```

Getting this error atm:

```
startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 3: Invalid variable name. Must start with a letter but was: ‘binding’
. At [3:30]  @ line 3, column 30.
   def build = this.getProperty(‘binding’).getVariable(‘build’)
                                ^

1 error
```

I have read the documentation from https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin at the end of page and tryed what they say with no results:

```
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.AbortException
import hudson.console.HyperlinkNote
import java.util.concurrent.CancellationException
 
// Retrieve parameters of the current build
def foo = build.buildVariableResolver.resolve("FOO")
println "FOO=$foo"
```

and also

```
System.getProperty('FOO')
```

Tested inside the console in plugin but still not working, any solutions?

Comment: Just try `return LOCAL_IP`, without `env` prefix.

Comment: Not working, getting this error startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 3: Invalid variable name. Must start with a letter but was: ‘binding’
. At [3:30]  @ line 3, column 30.
   def build = this.getProperty(‘binding’).getVariable(‘build’)
                                ^

1 error